# Where to get the repository id for the repositories in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, mantis

I am using Gitlab integrated with Mantis BT
All the required plugins are installed and configured

In Mantis BT, `Repositories -> Action -> Manage`, for the required the project click on Update Repository, in that we have a field called `Gitlab Repository ID`.
for that project. When I provided some numbers and updated them repository, the result in the change sets is changed but files and issues fields values are not getting updated.

Issues:

- How to get the repository id for the particular project in the gitlab?
- What is the problem for files and issues values for not getting changed?
  Need any configuration changes?

Answer (score 4):

In the gitlab you have to navigate to the api exposed by GitLab to retrieve the required details.

First of all, you need the project_id for your project. This is exposed via **CI_PROJECT_ID** variable by GitLab.
From the UI, navigate to the project and you would see the project id below the project name.

Once you have the project id then access the following url

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/projectId/registry/repositories
```

this will give you a json response showing all repositories under the project. And you find the **id** from the response.

```
[{"id":876,"name":"","path":"group-name/subgroup-name/project-name","project_id":4099,"location":"registry.gitlab.example.com/group-name/subgroup-name/project-name","created_at":"2022-01-06T12:39:28.326Z","cleanup_policy_started_at":null}]
```

Now using this ID, you can further navigate to the API to fetch more details like container image tags.

for e.g.

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/**4099**/registry/repositories/**876**/tags
```

or more specifically any particular tag

```
https://gitlab.exmaple.com/api/v4/projects/**4099**/registry/repositories/**876**/tags/**tagName**
```

Instead of accessing these from browser, it can be accessed from .gitlab-ci.yml as well.

for e.g. below is sample script for deleting a image tag from container registery.

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/registry/repositories/2/tags/v10.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [mantis documentation](https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration/blob/25d295994f9e44defd836f8c818893c1316d121e/SourceGitlab/README.md#mantis-repository-setup) states:

> `hub_repoid`: id of the Gitlab projet, starting from 1 for the first created project (auto-filed if reponame is valid and readable for the user)

You could use the [GitLab API](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/) to [get that id](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project)

```
GET /projects/NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <yourPrivateToken>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME
```

The answer includes its id:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "description": null,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "public": false,
  "visibility_level": 0,
  ...
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick way you have responded and the solution is very clear. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: This is sad that GitLab asks to use `repository_id`, but hides this value under some API endpoints.

Comment: @Nairum I agree. This is not very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can also try using the rest-client (a.k.a arc-client) plugin from chrome browser as follows:

```
http://my.git.repo.ip/api/v3/projects/?private_token=<my.private.token.from.gitlab>&url=<my.git.repo.url>
```

> my.git.repo.ip = localhost or whatever the IP/domainName is for you gitlab
>   server.
>
> my.private.token.from.gitlab = you can get this in gitlab > settings >
>   accounts > private_token, copy this and use it in the url.
>
> my.git.repo.url = my.git.repo.ip (or, url to your git repo should
>   work,also note: in the url replace '/' char with '%2F')

to get result like:

```
{
"id": 21
"description": ""
"default_branch": "master"
"tag_list": [0]
"public": true
"archived": false
"visibility_level": 20
...
}
```